# Accessing value from HTML form on another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I'm working on a project with 2 HTML pages :

- The first page shows name, price, and description.
- The second is an "admin panel" where I put a form where you can input the price, name, and description.

What can I do to link my HTML form to my second page ? Then, I need to link each result separately to each part ("What the Price"  input ->to the price paragraph).

For example:

```
<p class="burger price"> HERE THE RESULT OF <input type="text" name="price" id="price"></p>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I believe you will benefit form taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Sounds like you need a database

Comment: It appears that you were trying to say the word `Resultant` in your `<p>` tag, just letting you know that you're spelling it wrong if that's the word you were trying to use

Comment: It might be easier if you did a quick php tutorial somewhere. The answer would have little meaning for your unless explained fully and this would be quite outside the scope of an answer. If you can not get it working after looking into php  come back and show what you have tried and we can help you better.

Comment: Thing you are trying to do seem like not user friendly but you may achieve it by making use off localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make the 2 pages as `php` not `html`

Then you should use any databse to save what comes from the form

If you want to make it temporary then you could use $_GET

First you need to set the type of the form  as `get` and go to another pgae 
E.g:

```
<form method="GET" action="secondPage.php">
```

Last thing in panel page is set name to the `input` 
E.g:

```
<input name="price">
```

Now in `secondPage.php` you can print the price by :

```
The price is <php echo $_GET['price']; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, You are all right, I'll try to learn Php and then, ask my question if needed.